# Getting ‘Found UPDATE: Expecting:(SELECT..) error when writing ‘With CTE’ statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting the following error,

> Error ‘Found ‘UPDATE’: Expecting:(SELECT -or-,….. CYCLE or SEARCH)

…when running the following code:

```
WITH CTE AS (
   Select id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) + 99 AS New_id
From table_1
Where ID between 155662 AND 166046
)
UPDATE TABLE_1
SET ID =CTE.NEW_id
From CTE
WHERE TABLE_1.Id = CTE.id;
```

The reason I needed this is
, via rabbitmq, I accidentally sent data to the wrong table which included an auto generated IDs but I now want to update the id’s for those rows which I wrongly added so that the correspond with the correct table then I will insert them into the correct table then delete from table_1. I wanted to number only those incorrectly added rows, to match the numbering in the destination table. Note that the table was set to generated always and in order to make changes I altered it to be generated by default.

I tried this code but keep getting this error. Previous to trying this I had a slightly simpler code but then got an error about something to do with a window so searched online and this was the solution.

I am running this on oracle TOAD

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does Oracle really support the non-standard UPDATE FROM syntax?

Comment: Possibly it should be “ SET ID = SELECT CTE.NEW_id FROM CTE … “

Comment: You can only use WITH for SELECT statements, or within the USING clause of a MERGE

Comment: @NickW Thanks. I seem to get the same error appearing

Comment: The `update ... set ... from` syntax is added in Oracle 23c. However as Paul W mentioned, you can't use a CTE there.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `WITH` for `SELECT` statements. In your situation where you need a derived view to drive an update, use the `MERGE` command instead:

```
MERGE INTO table_1
USING (
   Select id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) + 99 AS New_id
    From table_1
    Where ID between 155662 AND 166046
      ) src
ON (src.id = table_1.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET table_1.id = src.new_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the possible solution. I’m getting a different error where it is expecting ‘INTO’ after merge, instead of the table name

Comment: Yea, typo... fixed

Answer (score 0):

I use MSSQL and MySQL so this is a researched answer. I believe with Oracle you can reference `outside tables` inside derived queries. If this is correct, I believe this should work:

```
UPDATE TABLE_1 T1
SET    T1.ID = (
    SELECT T2.NEW_id
    FROM   CTE T2
    WHERE  T2.id = T1.id
)
```